# Elementary product formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics, geometric-progressions

If $\omega$ is a complex number, $x$ is real and prime $p>3$, find the conditions for which
$$\prod_{j=1}^{p-1}(x-\omega^j)=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}=1+x+\ldots+x^{p-1}.$$

Comment: $\omega$ and $p$ are significantly constrained for this to be true. Please check the source of the question, and add the missing details.

Comment: If you want a counterexample for the general case, take $\omega = i$ and $p = 2$.

Comment: well, if w is not real then p is odd obviously.